# Apache htaccess rewrite rule works but how do I translate to nginx rewrite directive?

Tags: docker, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have a live server running Apache and a dev server running NGINX in docker. I wish to rewrite my sites urls from `/index.php?t=123abc` to `/123abc`.

This rule seems to work in .htaccess

`RewriteRule ^([0-9a-f]{6})$ index.php?t=$1 [L]`

However, I can't get it to translate to an nginx directive. My 'default' site conf is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /config/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /config/keys/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /config/keys/cert.key;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        rewrite "^/([0-9a-f]{6})/?$" "/index.php?t=$1";
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    autoindex on;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # With php5-cgi alone:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    }

}
```

The `/index.php?t=123abc` works fine but `/123abc` gives 404 error.

Please help

Comment: Change your rewrite directive to `rewrite "^/([0-9a-f]{6})/?$" "/index.php?t=$1" last;`

Comment: Yep - that seems to have worked. Thank you.